# Maven update manifest in dependency jars

Tags: maven, java-web-start

Webstart requires that all jar files has certain manifest entries, so now I have to go through all dependencies and update each manifest. Is there a way to get maven update manifest files in arbitrary jar files?

Ideally I would like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>

                <!-- something like this --> 
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library> <!-- does not work! -->
                </manifestEntries>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that **every** jar need to contains MANIFEST? I think it's needed only in Jar with your entry / main class. You can generate it using maven-jar-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
                <Application-Name>Your Application name</Application-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>${entry.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Webstart Maven Plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>keytool-api-1.7</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jnlp-inline</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filenameMapping>simple</filenameMapping>
                <versionEnabled>false</versionEnabled>
                <jnlpFiles>
                    <jnlpFile>
                        <templateFilename>default-jnlp-servlet-template.vm</templateFilename>
                        <outputFilename>yourJnlp.jnlp</outputFilename>

                        <jarResources>
                            <jarResource>
                                <groupId>your.package</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ArtifactId</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <mainClass>your.main.Class</mainClass>
                            </jarResource>
                        </jarResources>

                    </jnlpFile>
                </jnlpFiles>
                <unsignAlreadySignedJars>true</unsignAlreadySignedJars>
                <canUnsign>true</canUnsign>
                <libPath>lib</libPath>
                <codebase>$$$codebase</codebase>

                <updateManifestEntries>
                    <Caller-Allowable-Codebase>*</Caller-Allowable-Codebase>
                    <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
                    <Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>*</Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>
                    <Application-Name>ApplicationName</Application-Name>
                    <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
                    <Codebase>*</Codebase>
                    <Trusted-Only>true</Trusted-Only>
                </updateManifestEntries>
                <jnlp>
                    <j2seVersion>1.7+</j2seVersion>
                    <outputFile>your_jnlp.jnlp</outputFile>
                    <mainClass>your.class.here</mainClass>
                </jnlp>
                <sign>
                    <keystore>${project.basedir}/youekeystore</keystore>
                    <storepass>...</storepass>
                    <alias>your_alias</alias>
                    <verify>false</verify>
                </sign>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```